# Headerparam in Restful web services

Tags: java-ee-6

Hye. I have this code set up in Rest:

```
 @Path("companyTypes/{companyCode}")
 @GET
 public Response getCompanyDetails(@PathParam("companyCode") String permitTypeCode,       
 @HeaderParam(HttpConfig.HEADER_TOKEN) String token) {}
```

My ws will send companyCode through http like this "..ws/company/companyTypes/1" and what is @HeaderParam means. Is it related with @PathParam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5np/index.html)

> The @PathParam parameter and the other parameter-based annotations,
>   @MatrixParam, @HeaderParam, @CookieParam, and @FormParam obey the same
>   rules as @QueryParam
>
> Header parameters (indicated by decorating the parameter with
>   javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam) extracts information from the HTTP headers

Comment: Owh. Im understand now.. It is something related to the token that  request from headers like  X-Auth-Token:qp7384sr9v909u0e13l9u394l9m1rf. Thanks for ur answer